# Distribution of a random variable which itself is chosen from a set of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ are given random variables. A new random variable $Y$ is defined which is $X_1$ with probability $p$ and $X_2$ otherwise. How can the distribution of $Y$ be determined?

Explanations for both discrete and continuous cases will be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$\Pr (Y\le y) = \Pr (Y\le y|Y=X_1)\Pr(Y=X_1) + \Pr (Y\le y|Y=X_2)\Pr(Y=X_2).$$

Answer (score 3):

I will assume the event $Y=X_1$ is independent of $X_1$ and $X_2$; without this assumption, your
random variable $Y$ would not be well-defined.  The CDF of $Y$ is
$$F_Y(y) = \mathbb P(Y \le y) = p F_{X_1}(y) + (1-p) F_{X_2}(y)$$

Comment: Can you please provide a bit detailed explanation or proof of this statement - particularly in language of probability space?